# Issues with Javascript setInterval function on Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla1.5, setinterval

I added this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 2;
//console.log('Not broken');
$('.email_image li:gt(0)').css({opacity:0});
```

setInterval(function() {
   // function slideshow() {
    var m = $('.email_image li').size();
    x += 1;
    console.log('Not broken');
    if (x > m) {
        x = 1;
    }
    $(".email_image ul li:visible").animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $(".email_image ul li:nth-child(" + (x) + ")").animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
//    }
}, 5000);
    </script>
to the index.php of my template. I want to use the script to create a simple slideshow for some set of images. The loop just runs once and stops. Outside Joomla, it works perfectly but in Joomla, it just runs once and stops. Does Joomla have issues with the setInterval function. What is way around this issue?

Here are the links to the demos in Joomla and out of Joomla respectively
[Joomla demo](http://talonsoftwares.com/sweetroof/index.php?option=com_joomd&view=entry&layout=detail&id=1&Itemid=5)
[Outside Joomla demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wnws/2/show/)

Comment: The outside joomla demo is causing a few javascript errors. You can see them in the console/firebug...actually both demos have js exceptions.

Comment: I get `Error: $("jvbacktotop") is null Source File: /sweetroof/templates/jv_lago/js/jv.script.js Line: 110` - is it joomla that does all those addEvents in a jQuery page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though jQuery path is correct and included fine but `$` returns something other than jQuery (seems like a conflict):

```
function $(el){if(!el)return null;if(el.htmlElement)return Garbage.collect(el);if([window,document].contains(el))return el;var type=$type(el);if(type=='string'){el=document.getElementById(el);type=(el)?'element':false;}
if(type!='element')return null;if(el.htmlElement)return Garbage.collect(el);if(['object','embed'].contains(el.tagName.toLowerCase()))return el;$extend(el,Element.prototype);el.htmlElement=function(){};return Garbage.collect(el);}
```

Here is the error coming on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'css' of null
```

---

For jQuery, try replacing each instance of `$` with `jQuery`.

Or you can `$` like this:

```
(function($){
   // your code here
})(jQuery);
```